# How to move a discussion out of chat?

Tags: support, comments, chat

I got baited by SO to move my discussion into chat but I realized I didn't want to do that. Is there anyway I can move the discussion back into comments?

Could I have theoretically continued that discussion in comments forever?

Also, I think the system needs to change, the message is annoying and seems unnecessary.

**Edit**

And now I have to declare a bug after finding a new problem.

When I try to delete comments I made, I get a message saying I can only vote for comments every 5 seconds. Hey SO, I am not voting for comments, I am trying to delete them. Get that right.

I am adding a bug tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are getting the message suggesting you continue your comment conversation in chat then there's a good chance that the system has also raised a "too many comments" flag for the moderators.

The most common way of dealing with this flag is to delete **all** the comments on the post and put up a warning about keeping comments relevant and too the point.

If you are adding that much information to comments then you should really be thinking about updating the question/answer with additional information. Comments are really only provided for people to request extra information be added to the post, or point out possible mistakes in code (for example). They should be treated as temporary things that could disappear at any time.

Comment: This is a great answer. The only problem I have with that system is that there weren't that many comments(only about 6 or 7 between 2 people). Comments are necessary to clarify details. It seems hard to get to an answer, if you can't sort out problems. That's the nature of programming.

Comment: What is the problem in putting all comments into a chat, clarifying the details in the chat and leaving a comment explaining which things had been clarified?

Answer (score 3):

The discussion can be *continued* in comments; you are not prevented from posting more of those.

Anything said in chat, stays in chat. The conversation is kept indefinitely however; comments are more easily removed.

The message to move the discussion to chat is just a *suggestion*, you don't *have* to continue the discussion in chat. It'd be easier to interact with the other person in chat in real-time of course.

Comment: So, should I have ignored the warning?

Comment: @DarkMouse, Martijn is saying chat conversations is kept indefinitely, *but comments are not*. Comments can be (and are) removed at any time, so you should heed the warning if you want the information in the discussion to persist.

Comment: @DarkMouse It's just a suggestion: if you don't want to, don't. However, chances are that if you had 6 or 7 messages going back and forth between only you and another user, the problem would be better resolved in chat.